# SAP SQL IF Statement

Tags: sql, odbc, hana

I am trying to make a SQL statement where I want to show columns based on a condition. I tried the following:

```
IF (T0."Confirmed" = "Y") 
  BEGIN
SELECT T0."DocNum",T1."VisOrder", T1."Quantity", T1."Price", T0."CardCode", T0."CardName", T1."OpenCreQty", T0."CreateDate", T0."Printed", T0."Confirmed", T0."U_ACM_O_ETD", T2."DocDate", T0."U_ACM_O_LOS" 
FROM OPOR T0  INNER JOIN POR1 T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry", OWTQ T2   
  END
ELSE     
  BEGIN 
SELECT T0."DocNum",T1."VisOrder", T1."Quantity", T1."Price", T0."CardCode", T0."CardName", T1."OpenCreQty", T0."CreateDate", T0."Printed", T0."Confirmed", T0."U_ACM_O_ETD", T2."DocDate", T0."U_ACM_O_LOS" 
FROM OPOR T0  INNER JOIN POR1 T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry", OWTQ T2
  END
```

But when I try to run it, it tells me that there is a incorrect syntax near if statement.

> [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "if": line 1 col 1  '' (ECM2) (at pos 1)

Update:

I updated the code

```
select
      case 
        when T2."Confirmed" = 'Y' then
            (SELECT T0."DocNum", T0."CardCode", T0."CardName", T0."NumAtCard", 
               T1."DocDate", T1."ReqDate", T0."U_ACM_ORDERINFO", T2."DocNum", 
               T2."CardCode", T2."CardName", T2."U_ACM_CONTAINERLOAD", 
               T2."U_ACM_O_ETD", T2."U_ACM_A_ETD", T2."Confirmed" 
             FROM ORDR T0 , OPRQ T1, OPOR T2)

        when T2."Confirmed" = 'N' then
            (SELECT T0."DocNum", T0."CardCode", T0."CardName", T0."NumAtCard", 
               T1."DocDate", T1."ReqDate", T0."U_ACM_ORDERINFO", T2."DocNum", 
               T2."CardCode", T2."CardName", T2."U_ACM_CONTAINERLOAD", 
               T2."U_ACM_O_ETD", T2."Confirmed" 
             FROM ORDR T0 , OPRQ T1, OPOR T2)
     end
```

Updated error

> [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: line 8 col 1  '' (ECM2) (at pos 693)

Hope you guys can point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe you can post the text of the error message as text and not as an image?

Comment: Are you trying to write an anonymous SQLScript block?

Comment: @Abra This is my first time doing this so I don't know what you mean with SQLScript block. I just tried to rebuild the statement based on a statement I found on W3Schools.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added the JOIN but still get the error.

Comment: your SQL queries in IF clauses match, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Suncatcher Based on a column I want to show colums. So IF the condition is true I want to show more columns than when it's false.

Comment: i see that list of columns is identical

Comment: @Suncatcher Thanks for pointing that out, copied the code wrong. Column 'T2."U_ACM_A_ETD"' can only be shown when ' Confirmed' is Y.